# Theoretical: Two system integration through web service

Tags: java, web-services, spring, integration

I have theoretical question for you guys. Lastly i am coping with integration of two different systems which are exposed as web applications. Everywhere i read advice to do this via 3rd party web service which is kind of connector between two systems it is always architecture like :
`system 1 <=> WebService <=> system 2` 
and not like
`system 1<=>system 2`
 could not be easier to just create an interface in both systems and connect directly? can anyone tell me what i get by following WS approach?

Comment: You can link both systems if you control both of them. If you're playing as the integrator, you have to be the man in middle in this case.

Comment: I get it but is this conventional rule? Or there are some pros?

Comment: Logic isolation. The first system don't have to know about the second one, so the logic (and maintenance) is quite simpler. A good book to read about integration patterns is the [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/). You should read about [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) as well.

Comment: Thank You Gilberto, if you could, post this comment as answer so i can mark it as correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link both systems if you control both of them. If you're playing as the integrator, you have to be the man in middle in this case.

Spiting systems (and integrations) is good because of the logic isolation. The first system don't have to know about the second one, so the logic (and maintenance) is quite simpler.

A good book to read about integration patterns is the [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/). You should read about [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) as well.